# Is it possible to create Firebase topic messaging using C#/.net

Tags: c#, android, ios, firebase

For now i create topic using

[Create Topic](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_relationship_maps_for_app_instances)

in thats require one token

https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/**IID_TOKEN**/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME

right now i create thats token at android and ios.

Now as i need to create Topic with rest call at server side in c#

so anythings in that i am able to create that token at c# side and create TOPIC at server side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create token on server side.
Your application should register the device it is running on Google Cloud Messaging. Then your application generates the token and sends it to your server which can then use it.

See the Instance ID lifecycle [image: Instance ID lifecycle] documented here https://developers.google.com/instance-id/#instance_id_lifecycle

You can check this sample here: http://avilyne.com/?p=267
The client and server code are written in Java but it should be easy to convert it in its C# equivalent.

Comment: Hey Amaud, thanks for reply
i want this token to create Firebase messaging TOPIC and that's my goal,
so is possible to create topic without token or if i use authentication token the i able to create TOPIC ?

Comment: You have to send required information to your server. Then it can make REST calls to subscribe to TOPIC. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging#managing_topic_subscriptions_from_the_server